# Delete dynamically created report on close event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Access to create a dynamic report and I would like that on close event the report to be deleted.
Right now, I am creating the report like this:

```
Set rpt = CreateReport
With rpt
    .Visible = True
    .Caption = "Calendar View"
    .BorderStyle = 1
    .AutoCenter = True
    .ScrollBars = 0
    .Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
    .Modal = True
    .PopUp = True
    .OnClose = "[Event Procedure]"
End With

'extra stuff for report

strName = rpt.Name

DoCmd.Close acReport, strName, acSaveYes
DoCmd.Rename "rptNewName", acReport, strName
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNewName", acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal
DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, "rptNewName"
```

But, the DeleteObject will throw a error, because the report is still open..
How can I delete the report on close event?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following, just before you line DoCmd.DeleteObject...

```
Do While Application.CurrentProject.AllReports(sRptName).IsLoaded
DoEvents
Loop
```